# jhipster login popup appears in page instead of as popup

Tags: jhipster

My jhipster project was working fine.  Dont know what change went in that caused the below problem.

Now when I click "Sign in", there is no pop-up of the login form.  Instead the login form appears at the bottom of the page.  The page looses the focus and none of the controls are clickable.

Attached image of the problem.  Let me know if any part of code will be useful to debug.

I tried in different browser and faced the same problem.

Not sure which code to include that will debug this problem.

Upon clicking "Sign in", login form should pop-up.
Now form appears in the same page and page is not operable.

[screen shot](https://photos.app.goo.gl/Uj2fsJWmW1ecUqwS6)

First image is the normal home page.
Second image is the problematic page after clicking "Sign in".  The login form is found below the home page.

Comment: I couldn't find the problem image

Comment: added this link https://photos.app.goo.gl/Uj2fsJWmW1ecUqwS6

Comment: What jhipster version are you using? Is an Angular frontend, right?

Comment: you could also show the jhipster configuration to try to replicate the issue